# Loop through a set of names, taking action at interval

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In an HTML page using JavaScript/jQuery, I have an array of image file names (arListx). On that page, I have a routine called show(pict) that processes the image in certain ways, then displays it.

I want to simulate a slideshow by running each image through show(pict) at a specific interval.

The best luck I've had so far is getting the final image to show (evidently, all the images are run through the code but only the last shows).

Using my interpretation of 5226285 (settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value), I came up with this:

```
function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { show(arListx[i]); }, 5000);
}
.
.
.
//[main]
for(i=0; i<arListx.length; i++) {
    doSetTimeout(i);
}
.
.
.
function show(pict) {
    $("#OurPicture").attr('src',pict);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong and would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to incrementally set your timeout with `i*5000` so that they display at 0, 5000, 10000, 15000, etc.  What you wrote just calls them all after 5 seconds.

```
function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { show(arListx[i]); }, i*5000);
}
.
.
.
//[main]
for(i=0; i<arListx.length; i++) {
    doSetTimeout(i);
}
.
.
.
function show(pict) {
    $("#OurPicture").attr('src',pict);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Or you could just set the first timeout, then in the `show` function, bump the counter and set another timeout.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll have to study this to see what's happening, but I've incorporated the code and it works just as I've wanted.